# Pandas groupby get the smallest string

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': 3*['a']+4*['b'], 'name':['al', 'qwer', 'l', 'ewdbd', 'op', 'qsde', 'knmkln']})
```

```
id    name
 a      al
 a    qwer
 a       l
 b   ewdbd
 b      op
 b    qsde
 b  knmkln
```

I want to groupby id and get the shortest string in name, if there are multiple strings with the minimum length it can be any, final dataframe would be:

```
id    name
a      l
b      op
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: isn't `'al' < 'l'` or do you mean *shortest* string?

Comment: Sorry! I meant shortest, just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shortest **shortest** strings, you want to find the lengths first:

```
df.loc[df['name'].str.len().groupby(df['id']).idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
  id name
2  a    l
4  b   op
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `assign` with `drop_duplicates`, in most cases this should be faster than `groupby`:

```
(df.assign(length=df['name'].str.len())
.sort_values('length')
.drop_duplicates('id')
.drop(columns='length')
)
```

Or without the `drop` operation, which is relatively slow as [`Ben.T`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61236872/pandas-groupby-get-the-smallest-string/61237165?noredirect=1#comment108333495_61237165) noted in the comments:

```
df.loc[df['name'].str.len().sort_values().index].drop_duplicates(subset='id')
```

```
  id name
2  a    l
4  b   op
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked too but doesn't the `sort_values` slow the code more than the `groupby`?

Comment: No, I tested this on 700k rows, without the `drop` column operation, this is almost 2x faster than `groupby`. Weirdly the drop operation creates a copy of the dataframe, which slows the whole method down.

Comment: You can test yourself with `dfbig = pd.concat([df]*100000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @Erfan if you want to avoid the `drop`, here is a similar idea and faster according to my test `df.loc[df['name'].str.len().sort_values().index].drop_duplicates(subset='id')`

Comment: agreed that `sort_values().drop_duplicates` is generally faster than `groupby().idxmin()`, especially when you need to `groupby` on more than one column.